# DistanceFromLocation Error

Tags: ios

```
CLLocation *useOne = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:40.074744 longitude:116.240179];

CLLocation *useTwo = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:40.079106 longitude:116.243469];

CLLocationDistance distance = [useOne distanceFromLocation:useTwo];
NSLog(@"%d",distance);
```

But I got the result is "distance=1921570242" metres. absolutely this result was incorrect.

So where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Your calculations are correct, but the way you print is wrong. `CLLocationDistance` is a double, so format specifier in `NSLog` should be `%f` (`%d` is used for integers):

```
NSLog(@"%f",distance);
```